# Ways to write 'P => Q'

Tags: logic

Reading the Hammack "Book of Proof" Section 2.3

He lists grammatical constructions that are the same `P=>Q`

Most of them make immediate sense:

- If P, then Q
- Q if P
- Q whenever P
- Q, provided that P
- Whenever P, then    also Q
- P is a sufficient condition for Q
- For Q, it is a sufficient that P

But there are three more that I have more trouble parsing.

**Q is a necessary condition for P**
Every time I interpret it as 'Q being a necessary precondition of P',  thus `Q=>P`.   I guess I shouldn't read it as a causal "Q happens and makes P possible"  but more like, "if you have the P-is-true condition, then you must have Q-is-true condition too"

**For P, it is necessary that Q**
Again I read this initially as Q=>P, but I guess my mistake is that I'm reading these sentences as causal instead of of describing the states of P and Q.   ('P is true, thus is necessary that Q is true')

**P only if Q**
Again, as a condition of state, "you can only have P is true if Q is also true"

I'm trying to figure out my base error here, and I think it's that I'm reading these sentences as describing a causal relation rather than a description of how the states are required to be.

Is there any better way to explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be with understanding the ordinary meaning of the English translations. It can be hard to understand when the meaning is  stripped of its connection to your understanding of the world. So
a concrete example may help.

Let $P$ be "this is a ruby" and $Q$ be " this is red". Certainly it is true that $$P\implies Q,$$ because if something is a ruby then it is red; the definition of "ruby" requires redness. The converse $Q\implies P$ ("if this is red, it is a ruby") is false because there are red apples and red fire engines.

Now consider these translations of $P\implies Q$, all true:

- "This is a ruby only if it is red."
- "You can only have that this is a ruby if it is red."
- "Being red is a necessary condition for something to be a ruby."
- "For this to be a ruby, it is necessary that it be red."

On the other hand, the converses (which are false) should seem absurd:

- "This is red only if it is a ruby.". (No, it's a red apple.)
- "You can only have that this is red if it is ruby." (But it could be a red apple.)
- "Being a ruby is a necessary condition for something to be a red." (This apple is red and it's not a ruby.)
- "For this to be red, it is necessary that it be a ruby." (It is red, but it is not a ruby, it is an apple.)

Answer (score 0):

**Q is a necessary condition for P** means that in order to have P, Q must be true. This is a consequence of $P \implies Q$. It is not a sufficient condition though. Hence $Q \implies P$ is not necessarily true.

The other two statements follow the same line.